# Python Scapy Timestamp covertion

Tags: python, timestamp, scapy

I have a timestamp for pcap file:

```
Timestamp (170071769, 0)
```

I need to change the format for this

```
[2018-08-16 02:48:10.238506]
```

I use the first int whit `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int)`

but the answer is not the correct.

Comment: what is `170071769` supposed to represent? It certainly isn't Unix time for 2018-08-16 02:48:10.238506

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
t = 170071769                                                       
dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t)                                      
print(f"[{dt.year}-{dt.month}-{dt.day} {dt.hour:02d}:{dt.minute:02d}:{dt.second:02d}.{dt.microsecond:06d}]")
#  OR
print(f'[{dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}.{dt.microsecond:06d}]')
```

outputs:

```
[1975-5-23 10:09:29.000000]
```

if that's not the date you're looking for, you may need to convert the input integer somehow, or use a function other than `datetime.utcfromtimestamp`. Feel free to tell us more about where the number 170071769 came from, maybe we can help you figure out the necessary conversion.